# Installation Error for IJulia

Tags: installation, julia, miniconda, ijulia-notebook

I was able to successfully install Julia on my OS and I wanted to also access IJulia. This is from a Julia version 0.5.0 terminal.

when I entered `Pkg.add("IJulia")` I received the following error:

```
INFO: Installing miniconda ...    
/Users/.../.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/installer.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
/Users/.../.julia/v0.5/Conda/deps/usr/installer.sh: line 1: `<html>'
```

How do I mitigate this error? Is there another way to install a Julia Kernel on Jupyter?

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when `Pkg.build("IJulia")`.

I can solve it to follow [this instruction](https://github.com/JuliaPy/Conda.jl#using-an-already-existing-conda-installation).

In my case, I installed anaconda3-4.1.1 via pyenv on OSX,
so I typed some commands in console.

---

```
$ conda create -n conda_jl python
$ export CONDA_JL_HOME="/Users/MYNAME/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-4.1.1/envs/conda_jl"
$ julia

julia> 'Pkg.build("Conda")'
julia> 'Pkg.build("IJulia")'
```

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless 
if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site 
just disappears... **:-(** Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy 
the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing 
your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! **;-)** You can always 
leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your 
material...